# How to enable NTP sync on boot on debian wheezy

Tags: debian, init-script, ntp

I've installed `ntp`, which put the `ntp` script in `/etc/init.d`. On boot, I see that `ntp` is running:

```
root@unassigned-hostname:~# ps -ef | grep ntpd
ntp       4142     1  0 21:08 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/ntpd -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g -u 101:103
```

However, if I run `ntp-wait`, it waits forever. If I run a `dpkg-reconfigure ntp`, then the call to `ntp-wait` returns.

So it looks like `ntp` is enabled, it's running on boot, and if I force it I can get `ntp` to synchronize. But for some reason it's not synchronizing on boot (at least according to `ntp-wait`).

What do I need to do to get `ntp` to synchronize automatically on boot?

Comment: I'm not in front of a Debian machine at the moment, but it used to be that ntp init scripts would call `ntpdate` to force the local clock to match a remote servers', then start ntpd to keep it in sync. Separately, ntp-wait may be getting called by dpkg with different parameters that prevent it from waiting forever.